# How to Print Two Tables in a Single Report with Different Headers

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports

I am using Java, MySQL and iReport-3.7.6. I need to create a report with two tables. One contains Machine Production details other contains employees working in a shift. It should print date and shift wise.

I can merge employees against machines. Because there are one or more employees works in two or three same machines.

I need to get a report like the one below.

---

```
Date:04-03-2015   Shift - I

Sno    Supervisor    Machines      Employees
-----------------------------------------------------------
 1        Arun        1,2,4       Siva,Raj,Ram,James
 2        Kumar        3,5        Balu,Mano,Stephan 

Sno  Machines   WorkMins    Production_kg
--------------------------------------------
 1      1        480             800
 2      2        300             500
 3      3        480             1200
 4      4        480             900
 5      5        480             1000
```

---

and then only `Date:04-03-2015   Shift - II`, and so on.

If I use sub report concept, for example, I am giving for one day report means, it prints like employee table for all shift and then production table for shift on that day. But I need to print as above.

Can someone give me a solution to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a sub report, I know that you need a HashMap to build a sub report, then I propose the following:

1.- Create three classes:

```
public class RowEmployee {
private int sno;
private String supervisor;
private int [] machines;
private String [] employees;
// getters and setters
}

public class RowMachinesDetails {
    private int sno;
    private int machine;
    private int workMins;
    private int productinKg;
    // getters and setters
}

public class Shift {
    private Date dateShift;
    private List<TableEmployee> listTableEmployee;
    private List<TableMachinesDetails> listTableMachinesDetails;
    // getters and setters
}
```

The RowEmployee class is for the first table, the RowMachinesDetails is for the second table and the Shift class is for each shift of your report. As you can see, the Shift class has a list of RowEmployee and a list of RowMachinesDetails, because these lists correspond to each table, also it has a date which corresponds to date of the shift.

2.- Fill your lists with data of employee and data of production

```
List<TableEmployee> listTableEmployee = new ArrayList<TableEmployee>();
List<TableMachinesDetails> listTableMachinesDetails = new ArrayList<TableMachinesDetails>();

//Create instances of TableEmployee and TableMachinesDetails, and fill your lists

listTableEmployee.add(TableEmployee);
listTableMachinesDetails(TableMachinesDetails);
```

3.- Create instances of Shift and fill your HashMap with these instances, put the number of shift as key in the HashMap.

```
//Create instances of Shift

Shift shift = new Shift();

shift.setDateShitf (dateShift);
shift.setListTableEmployee(listTableEmployee);
shift.setListTableMachinesDetails(listTableMachinesDetails);

//Fill the HashMap

hashMapShift.add("I", shift);
```

4.- Finally, create your datasource as HashMap in iReport and use hashMapShift to fill your datasource.

NOTE: Maybe the type of variables aren't appropiate, the most important is the concept of the solution.

I hope this helps you.

Good Luck.

Comment: Except the jasper report logic, you have provided everything...